# ACE Editor Autocomplete to open on `.`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

If you enable live autocomplete, the tooltip opens up as you type things. However, it will never open up on pressing `.` until you type something else after.

So if I were to type `fo` there will be a tooltip trying to match `fo` to something (`for` or `function`, etc). However, if type `fo.` then the tooltip disappears, and it will not open until I type a further letter.

I have custom autocompletion keys, and I really want the tooltip to open up with all my suggestions.

Let's say I have `user` as a special key with `name, age, profile` as the suggestions. I want to be able to type `event.` and the tooltip to show `name, age, profile`. Right now, I have to type `event.n` for example to get `name` to show as a suggestion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57410925/4626775

Answer (score 3):

Use this snippet of code during the editor initialization to show the tooltip to open up with all the suggestions

```
editor.commands.on("afterExec", function (e) {
    if (e.command.name == "insertstring" && /^[\w.]$/.test(e.args)) {
        editor.execCommand("startAutocomplete");
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `e.args` is `null` for dot enter, and so is `e.command.name`

Comment: Also, I did try to use `if (e.command.name === undefined && e.args === undefined)` to fire the event, but the problem is, the AutoComplete fires first, THEN the getCompletion gets fired. So I don't actually get the list of object keys.

Comment: e.args is "." for dot enter and e.command.name is "insertstring", at least on my end..

Comment: However the autocomplete still does not pop up when it should, so I can't upvote this solution, sadly..

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for special characters (I needed the autocomplete on '.' and '{'. For some reason it is not working for '$':

```
@ViewChild('editor') public aceEditor: AceEditorComponent;
let editor = this.aceEditor.getEditor();
// create your completers
this.langTools.setCompleters(completers);
// trigger typeahead
editor.completer.showPopup(editor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple solution for that finally:

```
const doLiveAutocomplete = editor => {
  editor.insert('.');
  editor.execCommand('startAutocomplete');
};
```

Use `enableLiveAutocompletion` with a custom command `{ bindKey: { win: '.', mac: '.' }, exec: doLiveAutocomplete }`.

Using react-ace it's simply:

```
<AceEditor
  {...props}
  enableLiveAutocompletion
  commands={[{ bindKey: { win: '.', mac: '.' }, exec: doLiveAutocomplete }]} />
```